# How can I trigger an Azure Function ONLY once a document in Azure Cosmos DB has been created, not modified?

Tags: database, azure, triggers, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I've built an Azure application that runs perfectly except for one thing: my Function triggers when a document is created *or* modified in my Cosmos DB. I'd like the function to trigger only when a document has been *created*. Is there a way to achieve this?

I'd like to send a message to a user only if they just signed up. I periodically modify user states to run the app properly every day and I would like to avoid sending a "welcome" message every time I do so.

Comment: Are you using Change Feed for this?

Comment: @HasanSavran I just searched up Change Feed, and it seems like it's the default way that Azure checks for modifications in Cosmos? So I think I am, since I haven't made any configurations to affect the default settings.

Comment: There is currently no way to filter the type of events on Change Feed from the consumer point in time.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a property to your data model and populate it with some type of value for updates. This property will be always empty for inserts.
Or a dirty way to accomplish this is; you can check the _ts and compare it to now. If the difference is a small number, probably the it is an insert.

Comment: checking the _ts and comparing it to now doesn't indicate any such thing. `_ts` relates to the last modified date not the created date